# how to create sym link to pyenv specific python version

Tags: macos, python-3.7, symlink, pyenv

I am trying to create a symbolic link to /usr/u1/.pyenv/shims/python3 using following command

```
ln -s /usr/u1/.pyenv/shims/python3 /usr/local/bin/py3
```

changed to

```
ln -s  /Users/u1/.pyenv/versions/virtual-env-prj1/bin/python /usr/local/bin/py3
```

when I try

```
py3 -m pip freeze
```

Now, I don't get command not found, but It return empty.

Comment: If you cd to /usr/local/bin , does ./py3 work?

Comment: @Jake yes py3 open up the editor but I still can't run pip freeze command . I have updated the question

Comment: Could you try running this: `py3 -m pip freeze >> ~/py3log.txt` This should generate a  requirements file, if py3 is working properly. If it works, can you post the log?

Comment: @Jake it return empty

Comment: Hmm. I am honestly stumped. You could try re-installing py3?